# Android: How to change ListView item's value in Fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, notifydatasetchanged

I created a `Fragment` that has a `ListView` with several items. According to my plan, when I click one of the items on the `ListView`, I move to another `Fragment`, get data from them, replace the original data with the new one and update the `ListView`. In order to do that I wrote the code as follows.

1. Code inside the `onCreateView()` method

   ```
   listAdapter = new AlarmOptionItemListAdapter();
   lvAlarmOptionList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvAlarmOptionList);
   initializeListItems();
   lvAlarmOptionList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
   ```
2. The `initializeListItems()` method that adds several items to `lvAlarmOptionList`, the `ListView` instance.

   ```
   private void initializeListItems() {
       itemRepeatAlarm = new TextOnlyItem();
       itemRepeatAlarm.setTitle(getString(R.string.repeat_weekly));
       itemRepeatAlarm.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.never));
       listAdapter.addItem(itemRepeatAlarm);

       itemAlarmLock = new TextOnlyItem();
       itemAlarmLock.setTitle(getString(R.string.alarm_lock));
       itemAlarmLock.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.choose_option));
       listAdapter.addItem(itemAlarmLock);
   }
   ```
3. `onActivityResult()` method that gets the data from the other `Fragment` and modify the items on the `ListView`

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
       switch(requestCode) {
           case CODE_PIN:
               String value = data.getStringExtra(Keys.VALUE);
               if(value != null) {
                   Log.i(ApplicationManager.LOG, "PIN set to " + value);
               }
               break;

           case CODE_PASSWORD:
               String password = data.getStringExtra(Keys.VALUE);
               if(password != null) {
                   Log.i(ApplicationManager.LOG, "Password set to " + password);
               }
               break;

           case CODE_REPEAT:
               repeatType = data.getIntExtra(Keys.REPEAT_TYPE, 0);
               switch(repeatType) {
                   case Keys.SINGLE:
                   case Keys.PLURAL:
                       Toast.makeText(activity, data.getStringExtra(Keys.REPEAT_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       itemRepeatAlarm.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.on));
                       listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       onResume();
                       break;

                   case Keys.NO_REPEAT:
                       Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.alarm_will_never_repeat), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       itemRepeatAlarm.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.never));
                       listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       onResume();
                       break;

                   case Keys.EVERY_DAY:
                       Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.alarm_will_repeat_every_day), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       itemRepeatAlarm.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.every_day));
                       listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       onResume();
                       break;
               }
               break;

           case CODE_PATTERN:
               pattern = data.getStringExtra(Keys.VALUE);
               if(pattern != null) {
                   Log.i(ApplicationManager.LOG, "Pattern set to " + pattern);
               }
               itemAlarmLock.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.pattern));
               listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               onResume();
               break;
       }
   }
   }
   ```
4. And finally, the `onResume()` method

   ```
   @Override
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       if(listAdapter != null) {
           listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   }
   ```

I managed to successfully bring data from the other `Fragment` using the `onActivityResult()` method, but I keep failing to refresh the data in the `ListView`.

Comment: You should never call android's callbacks (e.g. `onResume`) from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onActivityResult` you are modifying the `itemRepeatAlarm` object , but it is not updated automatically in the adapter.
You need to get the object from the adapter and set it's value like this :

```
((TextOnlyItem) listAdapter.getItem(0)).setSubtitle(getString(R.string.on);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that onCreateView is executed after onActivityResult, so your item will be recreated with old values. 
Try this or something similar:

```
private void initializeListItems() {
    if (null == itemRepeatAlarm) {
       itemRepeatAlarm = new TextOnlyItem();
       itemRepeatAlarm.setTitle(getString(R.string.repeat_weekly));
       itemRepeatAlarm.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.never));
       listAdapter.addItem(itemRepeatAlarm);
    }

    if (null == itemAlarmLock) {
        itemAlarmLock = new TextOnlyItem();
        itemAlarmLock.setTitle(getString(R.string.alarm_lock));
        itemAlarmLock.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.choose_option));
        listAdapter.addItem(itemAlarmLock);
    }
}
```